# Trying to pass checkbox and dropdown results to a php file

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have made a form with checkboxes and 2 dropdowns populated by mysql.
I can get both to work on separate pages but cannot merge together in one form.
Here is my form code

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("test") or die (mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT name from aa";
$result = mysql_query($query);

?>
<form method = "post" action = "check2code.php">
<select name = "select1">

<?php
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $line['name']; ?>"> <?php echo $line ['name']; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here is the php im sending to

```
        <?php
print_r($_POST['day']);
print_r ($_POST['select1']);
?>
```

the error i get is
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 8 [5] => 9 [6] => 10 [7] => 16 )
Notice: Undefined index: select1 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/check2code.php on line 5

so the check box is fine the dropdown is not.

Comment: I suspect we're not seeing the full picture - the **only** time a `<select>` box won't send data in a form is when it has **no** `<options>` so I'd guess there's an issue with the query that means that no records are returned and the `<option>` list isn't being created... even porting all the `mysql_` functions across to something up-to-date (which needs to be done) won't fix the underlying problem I don't think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that no option is selected?  The var `$_POST['select1']` is only initialized if there is at least one option selected. Just try to select an option before you send the forms data to the server.

Comment: Unless the `<select>` box has the `multiple` attribute ... the first option is usually selected by default - hence why I suspect there are **no** options.

Comment: Hi Marcus Wolk altho a entry is in the dropdown its only passed if it changes, so i may make the default blank so it has to be changed. So you were correct thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try with `mysql_fetch_assoc`, not `mysql_fetch_array`.

Comment: or go the mysql_fetch_object() route and then you can use object notation such as: `$line->name` instead of the array style..

Comment: There's no real practical difference between `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))` and `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`